# Apache-pig Number Extraction After a specific String

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file with 10,1900 lines with Delimiter as 5 ('|') [obviously 6 columns now] , and I have statement in sixth column like "Dropped 12 (0.01%)" !! I am longing to extract the number after Dropped within  brackets;

Actual -- Dropped 12 (0.01%)

Expected -- 0.01

I need a solution using Apache pig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`REGEX_EXTRACT`](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#REGEX_EXTRACT) function.

Let's say you have a table `A` that looks like:

```
+--------------------+
|        col1        |
+--------------------+
| Dropped 12 (0.01%) |
| Dropped 24 (0.02%) |
+--------------------+
```

You can extract the number in parenthesis with the following:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(col6, '.*\\((.*)%\\)', 1);

+---------+
| percent |
+---------+
| 0.01    |
| 0.02    |
+---------+
```

I'm specifying a regex capture group for whatever characters are between `(` and `%)`. Notice that I'm using `\\` as the escape character so that I match the opening and closing parenthesis.